# What are this headwing that appear after Sailor Moon/Sailor Chibi Moon transforming?

Tags: sailor-moon

At first, neither Sailor Moon nor Sailor Chibi Moon have headwing.

[image: normal transformation]

When Sailor Moon first uses the Holy Grail to do the Super transformation, both of them receive headwings, or whatever these thingies are called:

[image: Sailor Moon's Super transformation]
[image: Sailor Chibi's headwing]

When the Super transformation ends, Sailor Moon loses her headwing. She gets them back each time she uses the Holy Grail or Pegasus' power to Super transform. But for some reason Sailor Chibi Moon can keep them indefinitely, even in her normal transformation.

[image: Sailor Chibi's normal transformation]

What are these headwings, do they have any power? Why can Sailor Chibi Moon keep them in her non-Super transform? Does this mean that her normal transform becomes a partial Super transform, and thus is enhanced with some powers?

Comment: They are essentially barrettes.

Answer (score 1):

Love the term "headwings". I always thought they were feathers.
Generally, as the Sailor Soldiers power up transformation-wise, their outfits gain more decorative bits. I don't think the hair feathers actually added any powers - unlike Sailor Moon's red bun decorations, which amplified her screaming to a weaponized level.

Answer (score 1):

Angels and swans and feathered mythology abound in anime as a symbol of transformation, like the ugly duckling turning into a swan. Here, it symbolises an overzealous little dork of a character who, after transforming into Sailor Moon, becomes graceful and elegant.

Comment: Do you have a source for your statement? And what about the actual question, i.e. what purpose they serve in-world and how they work?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the animators just screwed up and were too lazy to add another accessory to the head of chibi moon ... although you also could say it is a way to show the difference within their existence (between both moons that is)

Comment: But it doesn't differentiate them much time, because at first neither has the accessory, and eventually they both directly super transform and both have the accessory.

Comment: @Oriol true fact there